error disabling service broker on SQL Managed instance
I am trying to disable service broker on a SQL Managed instance. When I run this command
ALTER database segenresourcedb 
    SET DISABLE_BROKER with rollback immediate;

I get these messages:

Msg 1468, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
The operation cannot be performed on database "SegenResourceDB" because it is involved in a database mirroring session or an availability group. Some operations are not allowed on a database that is participating in a database mirroring session or in an availability group.
Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
ALTER DATABASE statement failed.

I am a standard tier. Also, I checked all mirroring-related tables and there is not data, I am still getting this message. I would greatly appreciate any help.
I was expecting broker to get disabled.

When trying to disable service broker on a SQL Managed instance using below query:
ALTER database <dbName>
SET DISABLE_BROKER with rollback immediate;

It fails with below error as shown below:

The operation cannot be performed on database "db" because it is involved in a database mirroring session or an availability group. Some operations are not allowed on a database that is participating in a database mirroring session or in an availability group.
Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
ALTER DATABASE statement failed.


In Azure SQL managed instance service broker is enabled by default and cannot be disabled. The following ALTER DATABASE options are not supported:

ENABLE_BROKER
DISABLE_BROKER

That may be the reason to get above error. For more information you can refer to the MS document.
